# button[][] to node -- java

Tags: java, javafx

I'll keep it quick. I'm trying to create a standard calculator. I want to use a `BorderPane` so I can keep my display:

```
 TextField display = new TextField();
 pane.setTop(display);
```

however I am using an array:
I then would want to use an array of buttons as a single object to place in the center of the pane.

```
 Button [][] keys = new Button [a][b];
 pane.setCenter(keys);
```

however I get an error:

```
Button [][] cannot be converted to Node.
```

I would like to know if there is anyway I can parse the elements to become/assume the value of a Node or if I can create a method to do so.

Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Why not add the buttons to a `GridPane`?

Comment: I added a gridpane and centered it in the borderpane--- bpane.setCenter(gpane)--- however when added the buttons to the gpane itself, i use a loop to automate it. here--> for(int i=0; i=list.length(); i++){for j.......){ gpane.add(keys[i][j],i,j) I get another error. Int cannot be converted to boolean. Sorry if i'm a noob lol. @trashgod

Answer (score 0):

The `center` node of a `BorderPane` is a single node. You cannot add multiple nodes there. This means you need to add them to a suitable `Parent`. `GridPane` would be a suitable candidate

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

    Button[][] keys = new Button[3][];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int num = (12 - i) / 3;
        Button[] column = new Button[num];
        keys[i] = column;
        for (int j = 0, key = 7 + i; j < num; j++, key -= 3) {
            Button button = new Button(Integer.toString(Math.max(0, key)));
            column[j] = button;

            // make button width resizeable
            button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

            // buttons should fill the available width
            GridPane.setFillWidth(button, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    GridPane gpane = new GridPane();

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        Button[] column = keys[i];
        gpane.addColumn(i, Arrays.copyOf(column, column.length, Node[].class));
    }

    // make 0-Button fill 3 columns
    GridPane.setColumnSpan(keys[0][3], 3);

    pane.setCenter(gpane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

As for the issue metioned in the comments:

```
for(int i=0; i=list.length(); i++)
```

yields an error since `i=list.length()` is an assignment and therefore the result is of the same type as the target of the assignment, i.e. `int` in this case. Java expects the middle expression in a `for` loop to have a type of `boolean` however. You confused the assignment operator `=` with the equality operator `==`, but here it should be inequality instead, since the loop should run as long as the length is not reached. Furthermore the `()` brackets seem suspicious to me, since there is no method in a array that returns the length, it's a field.

```
for(int i=0; i!=keys.length; i++)
```